# What Hibernate interview questions do you ask?

Tags: hibernate

We are interviewing new developers looking for someone with some hibernate experience. We are trying to put together a list of questions to test an interviewee’s hibernate knowledge. We’re basically using the test to verify that someone has a good grasp of how Hibernate works. Seems like these days people will list anything on their resumé. What questions would you ask?

Any tips would help!

Thanks so much,
Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three quiz on hibernate which will help you in screening the candidates

[Hibernate Interview Questions](http://www.skill-guru.com/skill/login/fetchRelatedTestsPosts.faces?tag=hibernate)

Comment: link is dead now

Answer (score 5):

1. What problem does Hibernate solve?

Answer (score 2):

Have them write some CRUD code in Hibernate, while they are at the interview.  You'll find out pretty quickly whether they are qualified or not.

Answer (score 1):

1. What is Hibernate?
2. How does Hibernate handle many-one relationships in the mapping file?
3. How do you maintain the mapping files for Hibernate?
4. What are some of the ways to improve the performance of Hibernate?
5. How can you support paging (in the front end App side) in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Have them explain to you Hibernate's different caching levels, it's important that they understand this.